# "ConfigurationBuilder" no contiene una definición para "SetBasePath" ni un método de extensión accesible

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Tengo este error al tratar de colocar onconfiguring en el dbcontext de mi aplicación que usa CodeFirst

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MotrCompnyConn"));
            }
          }
```

ya He cambiado el path a Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), no se cual es el posible error.

Estoy Usando DotNet Core 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente es agregar la librería adicional al

**using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;**

con nugget se busca Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;

se instala y desaparece el error

- Tener en cuenta que en core 2.x no aparece
- se debe seleccionar el proyecto de clase en mi caso es infraestructura.Data